# Como registrar datos en una BD haciendo click en un HREF?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo este código PHP que me permite saber si tengo amigos registrados(cuando entro a su perfil,esta el botón que dice AGREGAR),si el usuario es mi amigo dice AGREGADO.muy bien.Pero me gustaría que me ayudaran a que cuando yo pulse el botón(que es un enlace),este me ejecute algún código para insertar el ID de este usuario en la BD(Si no es mi amigo). Ya sea mediante ajax,no se.Pero claro cuando yo haga click.

Me gustaría que fuera dentro del ELSE.

```
<?php

 include_once('conexion.php');
if ($user != $my_id) {
 $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registros");
$quer = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (User_one =
'$my_id'     
AND User_two = '$user') OR (User_two = '$user' AND User_one = '$my_id')");

if (mysqli_num_rows($quer) == 1) 

{

    $mensaje = "<a href= '#'>Already Friends</a>";
}



else{

$mensaje = "<a href= 'agregarN.php?Id=".$user."'>No Friends</a>";

}


}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma seria con ajax.

```
$mensaje = "<a onclick='guardar(".$user.")'>No Friends</a>";
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    function guardar(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tu url",
            data: {
                iduser:id,
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("se añadio el amigo");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**PHP DE GUARDAR**

```
<?php
    $idusuario = $_POST['iduser'];
    //haces tu inserción
```

Comment: Gracias amigo.Al parecer lo ultimo que estaba mal era mi tabla de la BD "friend_request",nose si puede llevar la rayita debajo.pero en fin.Voy a hacer otra de nuevo.Gracias!!!

Answer (score 3):

Te pondría esto como comentario, ya que no es parte de la respuesta, pero date cuenta en el WHERE de tu consulta

```
WHERE (User_one ='$my_id' AND User_two = '$user') OR (User_two = '$user' AND User_one = '$my_id')
```

ambas condiciones son las mismas, creo que querías poner esto

```
WHERE (User_one ='$my_id' AND User_two = '$user') OR (User_one = '$user' AND User_two = '$my_id')
```

En cuanto a tu problema se me ocurre esto como solución
Cambia el else por algo así:

```
$mensaje = "<a href='#' id='id".$user."' class='enlace'>No Friends</a>";
```

La cuestión es crearte la etiqueta id, y que te registre el valor del amigo al que quieras insertar, si el id es 35, la etiqueta quedaría `id="id35" y el campo class, servirá para hacer la llamada al evento de ajax.

Luego por Ajax, podrías hacer la insercción

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready(function() {
          $(".enlace").click(function(){
              var id= $(this).attr('id');
              $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:" ", //Direccion de tu fichero php, que va a realizar la inserción
                    data: {id:id.replace(/\w/g,'')},
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        //Puedes poner una animación mientras se hace la inserción
                    },

                    success: function(data) {
                        var error=data.datos[0].error;  //Valor que te retornaría tu php, indicando si se ha guardado el amigo

                        if (error==1){ //Por ejemplo se ha insertado
                            $("#"+id).html('Already Friends');
                            $("#"+id).removeAttr('class');
                        } else{
                            alert("Error al realizar la insercion")
                        }
                },

                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("Error en el proceso");
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tienes un link como este:

```
<a href="/amigos/agregar?uuid=ab3853f4950p9" 
    onclick="agregarAmigo(event)">Agregar amigo</a>
```

Basta con hacer una simple petición AJAX:

```
function agregarAmigo(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const URI = ev.target.href;
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', URI);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if(xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
      // mostrar banner o algo que informe que ha sido agregado
    }
    if(xhr.status === 500) {
      // mostrar error
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

Y en el backend:

```
$targetUUID = $_GET['uuid'];
$userUUID = $_SESSION['uuid'];

$query = /* tu query */;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result == FALSE) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo 'Ha ocurrido un error';
} else {
    http_response_code(200);
    echo 'Amigo agregado';
}
```

Comment: error y mas error.

Comment: Y sin embargo no pones ni el `error` ni el `más error`. Es un foro para programadores, no para magos wey. Coloca tus errores.

Comment: error y mas error.Voy a la herramienta de desarrollador y me dice "401 unauthorized".Puse el codigo del backend en un archivo php aparte y utilize un "include"para enlazarlo.El codigo ajax lo puse en la misma pagina de perfil.Amigo podrias explicarme el codigo Ajax?Porque creo que le falta algo.

Comment: @luis ¿Viste la edición? El primer if (en caso la query devuelva `FALSE`, es decir, errónea, devuelves 500. En el else, devuelves 200. Mira la actualización y prueba.